# New android studio flavor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I just updated my android studio and ran into the following error.

```
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected scopes found in folder 'D:\****\****\****\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexMerger\dev_demo\debug'. Required: EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES. Found: EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES, PROJECT, SUB_PROJECTS
```

I tried closing, cleaning and building but it won't work.

Anybody encountered the same problem ?

Comment: please read this doc https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: Yup, I have this issue right now. Still looking for the cause, let alone a solution.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel can you be more specific about what we are supposed to get out of your link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It goes away if you downgrade the gradle plugin from 3.0.+ to 2.3.3. But still not the solution we need.

Comment: That is actually what I did but not satisfying indeed

Comment: An update on this issue, for me, it was caused by NewRelic, i was forced to add back the dependency, on project level and app level. No way to remove, anyone else had this kind of issue?
After that, i was able to up the gradle back to 3.0.1

Answer (score 6):

Deleting the .gradle folder from the project folder fixed this for me.

Answer (score 5):

Try This:

1. Delete the .gradle folder from the project folder
2. In `Android Studio` go to `File>Project Structure>Project` and change the `Gradle Version` to the latest version (4.4).

[image]

Comment: Even though now the latest version is (4.6), I was getting the same error but when I changed it to (4.4), fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution which works in my case.
I deleted the .gradle and .idea folder from the application source directory and then re-run the app.
It works fine for me.

I am not sure about the cause (might be related with studio cache), it works in my case.